# Open Self Extracting .exe

Tags: zip

I have a self extracting exe file that is password protected, does anybody know of a program that will open this? If I need to I can just run bootcamp, but it would be convenient to not have to do this.

Comment: Have you tried Stuffit from the app store? Also, crossover mac is a very thin "windows" wine emulation layer that might do the trick for a simple exe like that where you are just getting an encryption key in exchange for the passcode.

Comment: I'll give those a shot. I tried The Unarchiver, which is supposed to be able to handle self extracting exe files, but I didn't try Stuffit or crossover mac.

Comment: @bmike, you should probably turn your comment into an answer. I've tried that and it did work for me.

Comment: @JuanA.Navarro I've got tons of answers, if you step up and answer it and I'll up vote your answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Some self-extracting files can also just by unzipped using the command line 'unzip'. Just open Terminal, change into the directory with the .exe, and try running `unzip -t filename.exe`. You should see a listing of the files in the .exe. If you don't, then this approach won't work. If you do, you can make a directory and then extract the files, something like `mkdir extracted && unzip /path/to/file.exe`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is how I solved the problem. Following [bmike](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/5472/bmike)'s advice, I went to the App Store, searched for and installed Stuffit. When you open Stuffit, it opens for you a target where you can drag and drop the file compressed as a Windows executable. At least for the file that I've got, that pretty much did the trick.